# How does google profit from Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Google Cloud Messaging is free and how does google make money from it. Is there any catch in using GCM.

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**How does google profit from Google Cloud Messaging?**

One of the prevalent business model software companies and developers use nowadays is called Freemium Model.

> [Freemium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) is a pricing
>   strategy by which a product or service (typically a digital offering
>   or application such as software, media, games or web services) is
>   provided free of charge, but money (premium) is charged for
>   proprietary features, functionality, or virtual goods.

Google offers GCM/FCM for free at a certain extent. But, if you wanted to exceed beyond the FREE services, you have to pay for it. Just take a look at this [Pricing Plans](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for example.

Also, don't forget that Google's primary source of revenue is [ads](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/020515/business-google.asp). Let's say you have a successful working GCM/FCM app due to a large user base. When you integrate ads like AdMobs, Google also makes a certain amount of money out of that.

Lots of software companies are doing this- offering basic FREE services with an option to pay for an updgrade. You have Dropbox, Mapbox, Coronalabs and so on. The catch would be for users to keep using the company's products throughout and for the company to be able to gather data from them.